# D3: How can I find the largest length of my text labels?

Tags: d3.js

How can I find the largest length of my text labels? My code returns 93.8495px, but I can see that the largest is 246.8128px?

```
// Append legend labels.
var labels = svg.selectAll("text")
.data(pie(dataset))
.enter()
.append("text")
.text(function(d) {
  return d.data[0];
})

var maxTextWidth = d3.max(labels, function() {
  return labels.node().getComputedTextLength();
});
console.log(maxTextWidth);

labels.attr("font-family", "open-sans")
.attr("font-size", 16)
.attr("fill", "#333")
.attr("x", labelLeftMargin)
.attr("y", function(d, i) {
  return (i * labelHeight) - ((labelHeight * dataset.length) / 2) + keyRadius;
})
```

Comment: Try computing your `maxTextWidth` after you set your `font-size`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update 2017-08-09

As it turns out things are becoming easier with D3 **v4**. I added the simplified solution which should be the preferred one with the new version. Nonetheless, I will keep the original answer as a reference for those who are still on v3. Also, have a look at the side note at the end of the post, which is valid for both versions.

---

### D3 v4

OP's use of [`d3.max(array[, accessor])`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#max) is still not correct when it comes to v4, if for other reasons than before. The selection `lables` is now a [plain JavaScript object](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md) instead of an array of arrays as it was in v3. `d3.max()` on the other hand will work on an array, not an object. But, unlike v3, v4 provides easy access to the nodes of a selection by the [`selection.nodes()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_nodes) method which returns a flat array of the nodes it contains. This array is easily accessible by `d3.max()`:

```
var maxTextWidth = d3.max(labels.nodes(), n => n.getComputedTextLength());
```

Working snippet:

```js
var labels = d3.selectAll("text");
var maxTextWidth = d3.max(labels.nodes(), n => n.getComputedTextLength());

console.log(maxTextWidth);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<svg width="400" height="400">
  <text x="50" y="100" font-family="monospace">IIIIIIIIIII</text>
  <text x="50" y="130" font-family="monospace">MMMMMMMMM</text>
  <text x="50" y="200" font-family="open-sans">IIIIIIIIIII</text>
  <text x="50" y="230" font-family="open-sans">MMMMMMMMM</text>
</svg>
```

---

### D3 v3

Your use of [`d3.max(array[, accessor])`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#d3_max) is not correct: The function will return the maximum value in the given array. Although your `labels` selection is an array, things are a bit more complicated. A selection is in fact an *[array of arrays](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#group)* which is why your approach will not throw an error but will also not return a meaningful result.

Furthermore, in your callback which is supposed to be executed for every element of the array you are calling `labels.node()` which will always return the first node of the selection, which is obviously not what you want.

Although Mark was faster with his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34110978/4235784), his code has a little restriction which comes to play when operating on a grouped selection. As far as I can tell, this is not the case in your code, but a more general, more robust way of getting the maximum text width would be something like this:

```
function getMaxTextWidth() {
  var maxTextWidth = 0;
  labels.each(function() {
    maxTextWidth = Math.max(maxTextWidth, this.getComputedTextLength());
  });
  return maxTextWidth;
}
```

Inspired by Mark's comment on prefering `d3.max()` over `selection.each()` I kept pondering and came up with another elegant way of getting the maximum text width utilizing more of D3's own methods:

```
function getMaxTextWidth2() {
  return d3.max(d3.merge(labels), function(d) {
    return d.getComputedTextLength();
  });
}
```

This uses [`d3.merge()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#d3_merge) to flatten the *array of arrays* which make up the selection to hand it down to `d3.max()` avoiding an explicit loop done by `selection.each()`. Though I have never seen the use of `d3.merge()` on a selection it does no harm to the original selection and comes in handy for these kinds of operations which don't care about grouping and just need a flat array of all elements contained in a selection.

---

### Side note (both, v3 and v4)

Another things which comes to mind is that you are manipulating your labels' attributes `font-family` and `font-size` **after** getting the text width. These changes will obviously have an effect on the maximum text width. Judging by the snippet you provided it is not clear if this was done intentionally or not.

```js
var labels = d3.selectAll("text");

function getMaxTextWidth() {
  var maxTextWidth = 0;
  labels.each(function() {
    maxTextWidth = Math.max(maxTextWidth, this.getComputedTextLength());
  });
  return maxTextWidth;
}
console.log(getMaxTextWidth());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="400" height="400">
  <text x="50" y="100" font-family="monospace">IIIIIIIIIII</text>
  <text x="50" y="130" font-family="monospace">MMMMMMMMM</text>
  <text x="50" y="200" font-family="open-sans">IIIIIIIIIII</text>
  <text x="50" y="230" font-family="open-sans">MMMMMMMMM</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: +1, better explanation and answer then mine.  Although I still like the use of `d3.max` better then your `.each`.

Comment: @Mark Thank you! Your comment kept me thinking and I came up with another possible solution combining both `d3.merge()` and `d3.max()`. Please have a look at my edit. I have never seen it done this way, but it seems to be a really nice solution for these kinds of problems. I'd personally prefer this second approach and I am definitely going to keep this in mind for future use.

Answer (score 1):

You `d3.max` call isn't correct.  It'll always return the length of the first `text` in your label selection.  Instead, try:

```
var maxTextWidth = d3.max(labels[0], function(d) {
  return d.getComputedTextLength();
});
```

---

Full working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg>
      <text>;kladjflk;asdjflkjasdflkjasdfkl</text>
      <text>adkljfalskdjflk;asdfjkldddddddddddddasdjrrrrrr</text>
      <text>akl;dfjladksjf</text>
    </svg>
    <script>
      var labels = d3.selectAll('text');
      var maxTextWidth = d3.max(labels[0], function(d) {
        return d.getComputedTextLength();
      });
      console.log(maxTextWidth)
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As described, the solution only works if you have just joined the data.  However, if you are accessing previously configured elements, e.g. via

```
var labels = svg.selectAll("text");
```

The described solution will not work because labels[0] will be undefined.  In this case, one solution is to add the nodes() function to get the desired array and then omit the array index specifier in the d3.max call.

```
var labels = svg.selectAll("text").nodes();
.data();
var maxTextWidth = d3.max(labels, function(d) {
  return d.getComputedTextLength();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**For most arbitrary selections of nodes in some `svg`, the other answers are better.**

**However**, I suspect that many people will (like me) ask this question specifically in order to find the text length of the largest number on an axis for a chart.  In a situation like that, you know which item will be the maximum, because you drew the chart.  Normally it will be the last item; we tend to draw axis starting with the minimum number and ending with the maximum number.  In this case, you could get the maximum text length like this:

```
const labels = yourGroovyAxis.selectAll('text')._groups[0];
const maxTextWidth = labels[labels.length - 1].getComputedTextLength();
```

If you know that the maximum will be the first item, the problem is much simpler.  You can simply use `select`.

```
const maxTextWidth = yourGroovyAxis.select('text').getComputedTextLength();
```

Again, this only answers a subset of the problem space posed by the OP.  However, for those who are in the situation I describe, this solution my be the more straight-forward one.